# Laravel get focus on element

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am sending a mail through Laravel, and after sending a mail, a webpage gets reloaded. So, I'd like to get focus at FORM element after reloaded. Is there a possible way to get javascript excuted at specific moment?

Main.blade.php

```
    @if(Session::has('flash_message'))
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          alert('abcd');
          $('[name=sentMessage]').focus();
        });
      </script>
      <div class="alert alert-success">{{ Session::get('flash_message')}}</div>
    @endif
    <form name="sentMessage" method="post" action="{{ route('demo.store') }}">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
```

Controller.php

```
public function store(Request $request){
  $this->validate($request, [
      'name' => 'required',
      'email' => 'required|email',
      'phone' => 'required',
      'message' => 'required'
  ]);

  Mail::send('emails.contact-message',[
      'name' => $request->name,
      'email' => $request->email,
      'phone' => $request->phone,
      'msg' => $request->message
  ], function($mail) use ($request){
      $mail->from($request->email, $request->name);
      $mail->to('dlgocjs1@gmail.com')->subject('A Message From HCL Portfolio Website');
  });

  return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message', 'Thank you for your interest');
}
```

Comment: What moment? When the element is focused?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir after sending mail, i'd like to get focus on the form

Comment: And `document.getElementByName('sentMessage').focus();` isn't working?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir No, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementByName()` doesn't exist, only `getElementsByName()`.

Since you are using jQuery, you can do this:

```
$('[name=sentMessage]').focus();
```

Or use the `autofocus` attribute:

```
<... name="sentMessage" @if(Session::has('flash_message'))autofocus@endif ...>
```

Comment: I think <script> </script> inside@if ..@endif doesn't work. I tried to check if it is working, using alert(); However, there was no alert box tho.

Comment: Is `<script>...</script>` in the page source? Or `<div class="alert alert-success">`?

Comment: Well, you were right. The attribute "autofocus" is working well, but it should've been assigned to <input>, <button>, or <textarea>, not to the form.

Comment: You have jQuery installed? Is there an error in the developer tools console?

Comment: Oh, Yep, I thought I already added jquery, but nope. Thank you for helping me!